# TF-Gradient issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use `@tf.custom gradient` for a one of the layers in a RNN, and running into the following problem:

When I compute the gradient of loss in the output layer with respect to weights in hidden layer, I get gradient values, however when I try to compute the gradient of the output of the hidden layer with respect to the input to the layer or states in the layer (`y=f(x)` and calculating `dy/dx`) I get `None`.

I am using `tf.gradients` to compute gradients. I am doing the second part to see if I have implemented the custom gradient correctly.

This is the activation function from hidden state and output:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def _calcualte_crossings(x):
    """input :x : a 2D tensor with batch x n
    outputs a tensor with the same size as x
    and values of 0 or 1 depending on comparison between
    x and threshold"""
    dtype=x.dtype
    res=tf.greater_equal(x,0.0)

    def grad(dy):
        # calculate 1-|x|
        temp=1-tf.abs(x)
        dyres=tf.scalar_mul(0.3,tf.maximum(temp,0.0))
        return dyres

    return tf.cast(res,dtype=dtype), grad
```

**System information**

- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): Yes
- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Linux Ubuntu 18.04
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):
- TensorFlow version (use command below): v1.12.0-0-ga6d8ffae09 1.12.0
- Python version: Python 3.6.7
- Bazel version (if compiling from source):
- GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source):
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 9.0, V9.0.176
- GPU model and memory: GeForce GT 750M